# skipnullon="everywhere" mul3 works for json output and read somewhere that it can be used for xml, what about java?

Tags: mule, dataweave

I need to check for null input/output in a dwl transformation, when I use "skipNullOn="everywhere" with json transformation, it is perfectly fine. However, when used with java output like this:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java skipNullOn="everywhere"
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
com.mulesoft.weave.mule.exception.WeaveExecutionException: Exception while executing:  %output application/java skipNullOn="everywhere"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately I think its only supported with json, xml, and yaml

Comment: These are the only writer properties for java: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-formats-java#properties

Answer (score 3):

This documentation page shows the formats supported by DataWeave 1.0: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/dataweave-formats

As you can see some formats like CSV, XML and JSON have some writer properties that control how objects are written. skipNullOn is only defined for JSON and XML.

The Java format doesn't has any properties, because DataWeave maps Java types 1 to 1 to its types, so the conversion is not configurable.